# Configuring Atom Editor so that platform-ide-terminal opens by default with Label

Tags: atom-editor

Right now, every time I open a project, I need to create a new terminal and label it server, and run the command npm run serve. I think that is kind of tedious. Is there a way, there when I open that specific project, it will create a new terminal and label it server, and run npm run serve by default?

I was thinking of configuring init.coffee file in Atom, but I am not sure how what to write to achieve this effect. Are there any documentation for doing that?

The package for terminals that I am using is, https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal.

The image below shows how I want the atom editor to show up the moment I open the project. 
[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: So my take away for those who land on this page is do not use Atom, and use VSCode instead :)